How to complete the registration of LTL orders through the "mutation register" operation in Wayfair
I want to complete the registration of LTL orders through the "mutation register" operation.
After I submitted the request through "register", the following problems occurred:

The call to the https://api.wayfair.com/v1/bill_of_lading/CS542268116 interface did not obtain the bol content, and the error message returned was: BOL not available for non-large parcel PO: CS542268116

"Is order palletized?" at the bottom of the wayfair partner home->order detail page shows "NO"


Through the "mutation register" operation, I hope to achieve the same effect as "print documents", please see attach file: order-detail
The example of the GraphiQL Explorer is not detailed enough, please see attach file: example-page
How can the content displayed in the attach file: expected be achieved through "mutation register"?
